# Unpacking 'Non-Standard' Boot.img Problems for 64 Bit Device

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, 64-bit

This is in relation to [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/xcover-3-sm-g388f-root-5-1-1-t3365125/page4) XDA thread and [my thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/technical-bypassing-restrictions-t3452479) on xda. This is a [cross post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/samsung-unpacking-standard-boot-img-t3457265) from XDA, trying my luck on here.

Device specs, just in case someone asks

**Device Specifications:**

- **Current Android Version:** Android Lollipop 5.1.1
- **Chipset:** Marvell Armada PXA1908 (Note: Due to this being a rarely used chip, the CF-Auto root won't work)
- **Custom Recovery Status:** TWRP 3.0.2-0 (Not working with lollipop)
- **Root Status** (This is technically why I am here):  Android KitKat 4.4.4 (Root), Android Lollipop 5.1.1 (NO ROOT Yet)
- **ARMv8 64-bit**

Now let's get into my steps up to the point and then my problem.

Note: In the kernel readme it states to use the toolchain 4.8 but when I use it, it complains of not being able to find gcc. Also in the read me it states *"get Toolchain download and install arm-eabi-4.8 toolchain for ARM EABI.(64bit)"* and when [reading up](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html#syt) on it, it says to use aarch64 for ARM 64 Bit devices.

Device Source Code can be found at [Here](http://opensource.samsung.com/reception/receptionSub.do?method=sub&sub=F&searchValue=g388f)

```
cd ~/android
export CROSS_COMPILE=~/android/ndk/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-
cd ~/android/kernel
make ARCH=arm64 pxa1908_xcover3lte_eur_defconfig
make ARCH=arm64
```

This outputs: Image, Image.gz, .dts and .dtb files.

Where's the kernel readme (I believe this hasn't been update since kitkat) says the output will be,
    - Kernel : Kernel/arch/arm/boot/zImage
    - module : Kernel/drivers/*/*.ko
Note: when trying to compile with the 32- bit ARM toolchain it fails,  as the config is found in arm64, wheres other configs are found in arm.

So know I have a kernel (Image or Image.gz), and some .dts and .dtb files. Now to unpack boot.img, **this is where problems occur**. When trying to use tools like abootimg or the various different versions of unmkbootimg, they complain about non-standard boot.img.

[image: Non-Standard boot.img]

or

[image: Non-Standard boot.img 2]

While also try saving it as a zImage when its meant to be a Image.gz, or they extract it without throwing any errors, but when looking at the extracted files with a hex editor, it is all 00 throughout the files, therefore a useless file.

So therefor I tried manually unpacking with a hex editor and managed to get the kernel. Left is my Compiled and Right is the hex version.

[image: Kernels, Hex and Compiled]

Notice the difference in size, is this because the kernel in boot.img is stripped of its debugging items while mine isn't? If so I should look up on how to fix that.

But I am **having troubles trying to extract the ramdisk** via hex. 
So is anyone able to Teach/Help me extract the boot.img properly (with tools like unmkbootimg or with a hex editor)

I have attached necessary files if you want to have a look at them yourself.
Files: [Samsung xCover3 Files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5mtquWAP3MZjJQay1ERFprbnM/view?usp=sharing)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Numerous trial and error, I finally managed to output ramdisk.cpio.gz.
The start of a Gzip file in hex is, 1F 8B 08, therefor when using the search function in you had editor application you can narrow down your results to 1 or 2 files (2 Files for me as my kernel and ramdisk are both gzipped). You then follow it all the way down till you find a big bunch of zeros(seems like they are passing between files). When you reach the bunch of zeros include the first "00" at the end of the other hexidecial. E.G. End of one of my gzip files is "CE 24 00 00 00....00 (ZERO PADDING BETWEEN FILES), Threaded the end of my file is "CE 24 00".

Knowing this I was able to successfully extract and verify both my kernel and ramdisk files are correct.